# Do I get notified if one of my suggested edits is approved?

Tags: discussion, edits, notifications, suggested-edits

I found [this informative question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work) but it doesn't mention if I get notified when an edit is accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get notified, however if you still qualify for reputation you will see the additional +2 on your reputation for each approved edit, as well as your name as the last person to edit the post when it gets bumped.