# How can I check my suggested edits to see if they were approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where's the summary of your own suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92602/wheres-the-summary-of-your-own-suggested-edits)

How can I check the questions I suggest an edit for in StackOverFlow to see if they were deemed valid or not? And how can I see the total number of question I edited?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78408/do-i-get-notified-if-one-of-my-suggested-edits-is-approved and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85193/how-can-i-see-all-my-rejected-edits